# Read variable created with Open File Dialog Box in a function, inside another class

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to code a GUI which will allow the user to press a button "Open Simulation File", and from that create a variable "path_sim". The issue I am facing is that when I go to plot the file using this "path_sim" variable, it does not plot, as it sees the variable as undefined.

I tried passing it the function as "self.path_sim = open_dialog_box_sim()" but this causes another issue as it causes the file dialog box to open up before the rest of the GUI, which is not what I want. Is there another way to pass this "path_sim" variable into my class?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QFileDialog
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline


def open_dialog_box_sim():
    filename_sim = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
    path_sim = filename_sim[0]
    return path_sim


def open_dialog_box_exp():
    filename_exp = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
    path_exp = filename_exp[0]
    return path_exp


def simButton_handler():
    print("Sim Button Pressed")
    open_dialog_box_sim()


def expButton_handler():
    print("Exp Button Pressed")
    open_dialog_box_exp()


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.expButton = QPushButton("Open Experimental File", self)
        self.simButton = QPushButton("Open Simulation File", self)

        title = "Test"
        top = 0
        left = 0
        width = 1920
        height = 1080

        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.setGeometry(top, left, width, height)

        self.MyUI()

    def MyUI(self):
        canvas = Canvas(self, width=11, height=6)
        canvas.move(300, 35)

        self.simButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 10, 221, 61))
        self.simButton.move(30, 30)
        self.simButton.clicked.connect(simButton_handler)

        self.expButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 10, 221, 61))
        self.expButton.move(30, 120)
        self.expButton.clicked.connect(expButton_handler)


class Canvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=5, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        # self.plot()
        self.path_sim = open_dialog_box_sim() #############
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.plot()

    def plot(self):
        s = pd.read_excel(self.path_sim)
        plt.scatter(s.energy, s.Simulation, label="Simulation Data")  # plot the raw data
        xp = np.linspace(400, 2800, 1201)
        spl = UnivariateSpline(s.energy, s.Simulation)  # fit the data to a spline
        sply = spl(xp)
        db_entry = {  # puts the x's and y's together in one matrix
            "energy": xp,
            "Simulation": sply
        }
        df_spline = pd.DataFrame(db_entry)  # out the values in a pandas dataframe
        self.axes.plot(df_spline['energy'], df_spline['Simulation'])


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must rewrite the "plot" method to receive the filename so you can change the plot for each filename. On the other hand you must create a slot in the same class to access the variable without problems with the scope:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QFileDialog

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.expButton = QPushButton("Open Experimental File", self)
        self.simButton = QPushButton("Open Simulation File", self)

        self.canvas = Canvas(self, width=11, height=6)

        title = "Test"
        top = 0
        left = 0
        width = 1920
        height = 1080

        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.setGeometry(top, left, width, height)

        self.MyUI()

    def MyUI(self):
        self.canvas.move(300, 35)
        self.simButton.setGeometry(QRect(30, 10, 221, 61))
        self.simButton.move(30, 30)
        self.simButton.clicked.connect(self.sim_clicked)
        self.expButton.setGeometry(QRect(30, 10, 221, 61))
        self.expButton.move(30, 120)

    def sim_clicked(self):
        filename_sim, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
        if filename_sim:
            self.canvas.plot(filename_sim)


class Canvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=5, dpi=100):
        super().__init__(Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi))
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)

    def plot(self, filename):
        self.axes.clear()
        s = pd.read_excel(filename)
        xp = np.linspace(400, 2800, 1201)
        spl = UnivariateSpline(s.energy, s.Simulation)  # fit the data to a spline
        sply = spl(xp)
        db_entry = {  # puts the x's and y's together in one matrix
            "energy": xp,
            "Simulation": sply,
        }
        df_spline = pd.DataFrame(db_entry)  # out the values in a pandas dataframe
        self.axes.plot(df_spline["energy"], df_spline["Simulation"])
        self.draw()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```